# Xcode is not displaying the output upon successful build and run

Tags: c++, xcode

Currently,

I am using Xcode to do some programming in C++. I have the debug window opened up and running a simple program such as this one and there is no output. It is not running because the short cut cmnd+r is not working. How exactly can you make that shortcut work again.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Hi";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried a newline at the end of output?

Comment: you might need to flush the output as in `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`